# VSCode Debugger not Launching

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am writing a C++ program in VSCode. However, when I press F5, all it does is build the project. I tried making another simple project in VSCode to see if it works, but no luck. Here is my mini-program

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
      }
    ]
  }
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sum += i;
        std::cout<<"Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried reinstalling VSCode with no luck. When I try to debug a python script, it works just fine, so the problem is only with C++. How do I debug this debugging error?
CLARIFICATION: I am not getting an error from the debugger. Instead, the debugger for C++ isn't launching at all.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I am on macOS

Comment: I added the tag. I can't help with that OS. Hopefully someone familiar with macOS will answer.

Comment: @drescherjm It's not your fault, brother. LLDB can be configured the same way GDB does by using the **Add Configuration** method described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead, the debugger for C++ isn't launching at all.

Because you are missing the debugger's path in your `launch.json`. Add a path to the debugger within the `miDebuggerPath`.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",
      .
      .
      "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or, you can use the Add Configuration button (visible in `launch.json`) to set up a new debugging configuration.

[image: Debugger setup]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still didn't work. It is still not running the debugger.

Comment: @Aaryan, have you made sure that you have your debugger correctly installed? Try running it from an external terminal to check. Also, have you tried add configuration method?

Comment: I have tried both of those things, with no luck. Here is the message I am getting:
 *  Executing task: C/C++: clang++ build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g src/*.cpp src/chess_includes/*.cpp -o chess_engine

Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: @Aaryan Well clearly that is the wrong task. This is the name of your debugging task `"name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",`. The name you have in the comment above is different.

Comment: @RohanBari I am aware of that. This is exactly what my problem is. When I hit the debug button, it only runs the build task

Comment: @RohanBari I solved this problem, and got another one. I wasn't deleting the previous configuration, but now the debug bar shows for a second and then disappears. I found a post that might be able to help me with that

Comment: @Aaryan Not sure about that problem. Check whether the particular thread helps you or not. If not, then you can freely post a new question about it. But ensure that you provide sufficient details to avoid the questions from getting downvoted or being closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps and see if it works:

- do not forget to save file with 'ctrl + s' before running it.
- include path of c++ "bin" folder to your environment variables, vs code automatically detects c++ debugger.
- install code runner extension on vs code.

do share your results..